# Cannot use Options API in Vue 3 with Webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, webpack-5

I have a question about the Options API in Vue 3 which might be specific to my implementation with Webpack 5. From the docs and articles it seems that in Vue 3 you can use both the 'old' Options API and the 'new' Composition API interchangeably in Vue 3.

However when I have the following code in my Vue 3 app:

```
<template>
  <div class="blog-overview__filters">
    <button @click="filter()" class="filter filter__option">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Filters",
  methods: {
    filter() {
      console.log('Hello')
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I get the following warnings:
`Unhandled error during execution of native event handler`
`$options.filter is not a function`

When I use the setup function for the Composition API it works properly:

```
export default {
  name: "Filters",
  setup() {
    const filter = () => {
      console.log('Hello')
    }
    return {
      filter
    }
  }
};
```

The same goes for other Options API methods.

The below Options API code does nothing in Vue 3:

```
export default {
  name: "Blogs",
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    let endpoint = "endpoints/blog-overview.json";
    axios
      .get(endpoint)
      .then((res) => {
        this.blogs = res.data.blogs;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log({ err });
      });
  },
};
```

But the Composition API works just fine:

```
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Blogs",
  setup() {
    const blogs = ref([]);
    onMounted(() => {
      let endpoint = "endpoints/blog-overview.json";
      axios
        .get(endpoint)
        .then((res) => {
          blogs.value = res.data.blogs;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log({ err });
        });
    });
    
    return {
      blogs
    }
  },
};
```

Are we not supposed to be able to continue using the Options API in Vue 3?

My setup is:
`webpack: 5.65.0`
`vue: 3.2.26`
`vue-loader: 17.0.0`
`@vue/compiler-sfc: 3.2.26`

Comment: Have you tried `@click="filter"` - i.e. not calling the method but just refer to it ? Did you try with different name, e.g. `filtration` instead of `filter` ?

Comment: Yes I tried both but to no avail

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-cli-c3zkyj?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FFilters.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, a few weeks ago when I updated the basic boilerplate for our agency's projects to Webpack 5 I added the below in the webpack config:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
  __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false
})
```

But this turns the options API off, I believe to reduce bundle size and improve performance. Simply setting `__VUE_OPTIONS_API__` to `true` did the trick for me.

Additionally I also realised I don't need `@vue/compiler-sfc` since I am using a Vue version of 3.2.13 or higher